# Association with STI Inheritance in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sti

I have problems associating an entity with another using a OneToOne Association, where one entity is an instance of a Single-Table-Inheritance subclass.

I have one superclass, let's call it **Animal**, and some subclasses, e.g. **Cat, Dog**.
The animal contains an `object_id` **column** which points to the ID of the owner and a **discriminator column** `type` which points to the subclass (cat or dog).

I also have different entities which have one-to-one associations with one of the subclasses.

- **CatLady** 1 <-> 1 **Cat** *(OK, bad example.. A Cat lady should own more than just one cat)*
- **DogOwner** 1 <-> 1 **Dog**

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Animal
 *
 * @ORM\Table("animal")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="integer")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({0 = "Cat", 1 = "Dog"})
 */
abstract class Animal { 
 /**
  * @var integer
  * @ORM\Id()
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  */
 protected $id;

 /**
  * @var integer
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="object_id", type="integer")
  */
  protected $object_id;
}

/**
 * Cat
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Cat extends Animal {}

/**
 * CatLady
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class CatLady {
  /**
   * @var Cat
   *
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Path\To\Entity\Cat")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="object_id", nullable=true))
   */
  private $cat;
}
```

**Problem:**
Before updating Doctrine from 2.3 to 2.4.5 it worked, but after I always got a `Primary Key Value is Missing Exception`.
Now I am trying to figure out how to create this association between the CatLady and the Cat. The association may be unidirectional.

I guess the problem is, that the `object_id` is not an **primary key** - which is not possible because it is not unique (only object_id and type would be unique, but the discriminator cannot be part of the primary key...).

Any solutions?

**Update:**
Maybe some more information will help:
As mentioned I am using Doctrine 2.4.5 and Symfony2.2. The last working version was with Doctrine 2.3 and Symfony2.1.
The column `object_id` is neither a Primary Key nor a Foreign Key, because it is not unqiue and points to different classes/tables. This is maybe not the best database design, but I can't change it.

```
Table: Animal
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| object_id      | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| object_type    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The tables for CatLady and DogOwner don't have a column pointing to Animal.

Comment: I may be wroong but I think you inverted things in  the joint:@ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true))